# Is there any way to vectorize this matlab code?

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization, nested-loops, mex

I have the following code:

```
function [Ps,Pd,Pv] = Arii2010_Modified_1Pixel(C11,C12_imag,C12_real,C13_imag,C13_real,C22,C23_imag,C23_real,C33)
MeanOrientationAngleStep = 1/100;
StandardDeviationStep = 1/100;
NumberOfAngles = floor(2*pi/MeanOrientationAngleStep);
NumberOfStandandardDeviations = 1/StandardDeviationStep;
for i = 0:NumberOfAngles
    for j = 0:NumberOfStandandardDeviations
        theta = -pi+i*MeanOrientationAngleStep;
        sigma = j*StandardDeviationStep;
        Fv = FindFv(sigma,theta,C11,C12_imag,C12_real,C13_imag,C13_real,C22,C23_imag,C23_real,C33);
    end
end
end

function Fv = FindFv(sigma,theta,C11,C12_imag,C12_real,C13_imag,C13_real,C22,C23_imag,C23_real,C33)
coef1 = 1/2-(((1-2*sigma^2)*(1-sigma^2)*cos(2*theta))/(2*(1+sigma^2)));
coef2 = ((1-4*sigma^2)*(1-3*sigma^2)*(1-2*sigma^2)*(1-sigma^2)*cos(4*theta))/(8*(1+sigma^2)*(1+2*sigma^2)*(1+3*sigma^2));
coef3 = ((1-2*sigma^2)*(1-sigma^2)*sin(2*theta))/(2*sqrt(2)*(1+sigma^2));
coef4 = ((1-4*sigma^2)*(1-3*sigma^2)*(1-2*sigma^2)*(1-sigma^2)*sin(4*theta))/(4*sqrt(2)*(1+sigma^2)*(1+2*sigma^2)*(1+3*sigma^2));
Fv1 = C11/(coef1+coef2);
aQuadratic1 = -2*coef2*(coef1+coef2);
aQuadratic2 = (coef3-coef4)^2;
aQuadratic = aQuadratic1 - aQuadratic2;
bQuadratic1 = 2*C11*coef2-C22*(coef1+coef2);
bQuadratic2 = -2*C12_real*(coef3-coef4);
bQuadratic = bQuadratic1 - bQuadratic2;
cQuadratic1 = C11*C22;
cQuadratic2 = C12_real^2+C12_imag^2;
cQuadratic = cQuadratic1 - cQuadratic2;
rQuadratic = roots([aQuadratic bQuadratic cQuadratic]);
sel1 = rQuadratic == real(rQuadratic);
rQuadratic = rQuadratic(sel1);
sel2 = rQuadratic == abs(rQuadratic);
rQuadratic = rQuadratic(sel2);
Fv2 = max(rQuadratic);
aCubic1 = 2*coef2*(1-coef1+coef2)*(coef1+coef2);
aCubic2 = 2*coef2*(coef3-coef4)*(coef3+coef4);
aCubic3 = -(coef1+coef2)*(coef3+coef4)^2;
aCubic4 = 2*coef2^3;
aCubic5 = -(1-coef1+coef2)*(coef3-coef4)^2;
aCubic = aCubic1+aCubic2-aCubic3-aCubic4-aCubic5;
bCubic1 = -2*coef2*(C11*(1-coef1+coef2)+C33*(coef1+coef2))+C22*(1-coef1+coef2)*(coef1+coef2);
bCubic2 = -2*coef2*(C23_real*(coef3-coef4)+C12_real*(coef3+coef4))+2*C13_real*(coef3-coef4)*(coef3+coef4);
bCubic3 = 2*C23_real*(coef1+coef2)*(coef3+coef4)+C11*(coef3+coef4)^2;
bCubic4 = (4*C13_real+C22)*coef2^2;
bCubic5 = 2*C12_real*(1-coef1+coef2)*(coef3-coef4)+C33*(coef3-coef4)^2;
bCubic = bCubic1+bCubic2-bCubic3-bCubic4-bCubic5;
cCubic1 = 2*C11*C33*coef2-C11*C22*(1-coef1+coef2)-C22*C33*(coef1+coef2);
cCubic2 = 2*(C12_real*C23_real-C12_imag*C23_imag)*coef2-2*(C13_real*C23_real+C13_imag*C23_imag)*...
    (coef3-coef4)-2*(C12_real*C13_real+C12_imag*C13_imag)*(coef3+coef4);
cCubic3 = -(C23_real^2+C23_imag^2)*(coef1+coef2)-2*C11*C23_real*(coef3+coef4);
cCubic4 = 2*(C13_real^2+C13_imag^2+C13_real*C22)*coef2;
cCubic5 = -(C12_real^2+C12_imag^2)*(1-coef1+coef2)-2*C33*C12_real*(coef3-coef4);
cCubic = cCubic1+cCubic2-cCubic3-cCubic4-cCubic5;
dCubic1 = C11*C22*C33;
dCubic2 = 2*(C12_real*(C13_real*C23_real+C13_imag*C23_imag)+C12_imag*(C13_imag*C23_real-C13_real*C23_imag));
dCubic3 = C11*(C23_real^2+C23_imag^2);
dCubic4 = C22*(C13_real^2+C13_imag^2);
dCubic5 = C33*(C12_real^2+C12_imag^2);
dCubic = dCubic1+dCubic2-dCubic3-dCubic4-dCubic5;
rCubic = roots([aCubic bCubic cCubic dCubic]);
sel3 = rCubic == real(rCubic);
rCubic = rCubic(sel3);
sel4 = rCubic == abs(rCubic);
rCubic = rCubic(sel4);
Fv3 = max(rCubic);
Fv = min([Fv1 Fv2 Fv3]);
end
```

I'm wondering if there's any function like `bsxfun`, `blockproc` or `arrayfun` to vectorize this part of the code?

```
for i = 0:NumberOfAngles
    for j = 0:NumberOfStandandardDeviations
        theta = -pi+i*MeanOrientationAngleStep;
        sigma = j*StandardDeviationStep;
        Fv = FindFv(sigma,theta,C11,C12_imag,C12_real,C13_imag,C13_real,C22,C23_imag,C23_real,C33);
    end
end
```

Comment: Since `FindFv` seems to contain `roots`, which accepts one polynomial at a time, I don't think you can vectorize much: you probably need to call `FindFv` `NumberOfAngles*NumberOfStandandardDeviations` times. If it wasn't for this, you could vectorize every operation in `FindFv`, and use `max/min` with optional input arguments along dimensions of interest. It *could* help to vectorize everything before the `roots`, and use the double loop just to cover every polynomial. It would be faster, but I don't know how much.

Comment: @AndrasDeak infact I don't want to vectorize the code inside the `FindFv` function. I want to vectorize the part `for i = 0:NumberOfAngles
    for j = 0:NumberOfStandandardDeviations
        theta = -pi+i*MeanOrientationAngleStep;
        sigma = j*StandardDeviationStep;
        Fv = FindFv(sigma,theta,C11,C12_imag,C12_real,C13_imag,C13_real,C22,C23_imag,C23_real,C33);
    end
end` which is invoking the `FindFv` function

Comment: Unfortunately, vectorization is not a recipe involving magic wands and pixie dust:) If you're calling a function 1000 times and the function can only work one at a time, then there's not much you can do. There is *one* thing: rewriting the function in MEX and pre-compiling it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Can you explain more about the last sentence and introduce good resources to start?

Comment: MEX is a way to write C code which interfaces with matlab not-so-impossibly. [Some docs and examples are here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html). Using MEX is a pain in the butt, due to C and subtle issues one can easily encounter. But it uses compiled code, so it's faster than high-level MATLAB. Anyway, I'm neither too versed in MEX, nor in proper vectorization. I'd try first vectorizing your function and putting the loop around just the `roots` bit, that might be simpler/faster. I really don't know your odds.

Comment: @AndrasDeak ok, I am almost familiar with C. I'll try to change my code a bit and isolate the for loops just around the roots function and then I will see if it's ecconomical to implement that small part faster using mex files

Comment: Well, you are not using the output of FindFv.

Comment: @WolfgangKuehn the code isn't complete. Of course, I will use it later. Please help me and make me aware of your slightest brainstorm. Performance and timing of the code is the most important issue in this implementation :)

Comment: sepideh, I've just noticed that with more than 90 questions so far, you have almost 60 without an accepted answer. Don't take this the wrong way, but please consider accepting answers for your questions if they give a solution to your problem. If they don't, feel free to inform answerers that something's missing. Having a bunch of questions apparently without solutions is unhealthy for the site, and accepting (when deserved) makes answerers worth their time helping you:)

Comment: I believe you have a `norm(C12*C13*C23')^2` in there, but in much longer terms. Using complex numbers may improve speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've commented that you should probably either put the loops inside your vectorized worker function, or/and use compiled MEX code. Here's my take on the first approach:

```
function [Ps,Pd,Pv] = Arii2010_Modified_1Pixel(C11,C12_imag,C12_real,C13_imag,C13_real,C22,C23_imag,C23_real,C33)
MeanOrientationAngleStep = 1/100;
StandardDeviationStep = 1/100;
NumberOfAngles = floor(2*pi/MeanOrientationAngleStep);
NumberOfStandandardDeviations = 1/StandardDeviationStep;

%// set up vectorized input
thetav = -pi + (0:NumberOfAngles)*MeanOrientationAngleStep;
sigmav = (0:NumberOfStandandardDeviations)*StandardDeviationStep;

%// grid for parameter pairs
[theta, sigma] = meshgrid(thetav,sigmav);

%// run vectorized function
Fv_vec = FindFv_vec(sigma,theta,C11,C12_imag,C12_real,C13_imag,C13_real,C22,C23_imag,C23_real,C33);
end


function Fv_vec = FindFv_vec(sigma,theta,C11,C12_imag,C12_real,C13_imag,C13_real,C22,C23_imag,C23_real,C33)
coef1 = 1./2-(((1-2.*sigma.^2).*(1-sigma.^2).*cos(2.*theta))./(2.*(1+sigma.^2)));
coef2 = ((1-4.*sigma.^2).*(1-3.*sigma.^2).*(1-2.*sigma.^2).*(1-sigma.^2).*cos(4.*theta))./(8.*(1+sigma.^2).*(1+2.*sigma.^2).*(1+3.*sigma.^2));
coef3 = ((1-2.*sigma.^2).*(1-sigma.^2).*sin(2.*theta))./(2.*sqrt(2).*(1+sigma.^2));
coef4 = ((1-4.*sigma.^2).*(1-3.*sigma.^2).*(1-2.*sigma.^2).*(1-sigma.^2).*sin(4.*theta))./(4.*sqrt(2).*(1+sigma.^2).*(1+2.*sigma.^2).*(1+3.*sigma.^2));
%// this is OK:
Fv1 = C11./(coef1+coef2);

aQuadratic1 = -2.*coef2.*(coef1+coef2);
aQuadratic2 = (coef3-coef4).^2;
aQuadratic = aQuadratic1 - aQuadratic2;
bQuadratic1 = 2.*C11.*coef2-C22.*(coef1+coef2);
bQuadratic2 = -2.*C12_real.*(coef3-coef4);
bQuadratic = bQuadratic1 - bQuadratic2;
cQuadratic1 = C11.*C22;
cQuadratic2 = C12_real.^2+C12_imag.^2;
cQuadratic = cQuadratic1 - cQuadratic2;
%// move this down to one block for looping:
%//rQuadratic = roots([aQuadratic bQuadratic cQuadratic]);
%//sel1 = rQuadratic == real(rQuadratic);
%//rQuadratic = rQuadratic(sel1);
%//sel2 = rQuadratic == abs(rQuadratic);
%//rQuadratic = rQuadratic(sel2);
%//Fv2 = max(rQuadratic);

aCubic1 = 2.*coef2.*(1-coef1+coef2).*(coef1+coef2);
aCubic2 = 2.*coef2.*(coef3-coef4).*(coef3+coef4);
aCubic3 = -(coef1+coef2).*(coef3+coef4).^2;
aCubic4 = 2.*coef2.^3;
aCubic5 = -(1-coef1+coef2).*(coef3-coef4).^2;
aCubic = aCubic1+aCubic2-aCubic3-aCubic4-aCubic5;
bCubic1 = -2.*coef2.*(C11.*(1-coef1+coef2)+C33.*(coef1+coef2))+C22.*(1-coef1+coef2).*(coef1+coef2);
bCubic2 = -2.*coef2.*(C23_real.*(coef3-coef4)+C12_real.*(coef3+coef4))+2.*C13_real.*(coef3-coef4).*(coef3+coef4);
bCubic3 = 2.*C23_real.*(coef1+coef2).*(coef3+coef4)+C11.*(coef3+coef4).^2;
bCubic4 = (4.*C13_real+C22).*coef2.^2;
bCubic5 = 2.*C12_real.*(1-coef1+coef2).*(coef3-coef4)+C33.*(coef3-coef4).^2;
bCubic = bCubic1+bCubic2-bCubic3-bCubic4-bCubic5;
cCubic1 = 2.*C11.*C33.*coef2-C11.*C22.*(1-coef1+coef2)-C22.*C33.*(coef1+coef2);
cCubic2 = 2.*(C12_real.*C23_real-C12_imag.*C23_imag).*coef2-2.*(C13_real.*C23_real+C13_imag.*C23_imag).*...
    (coef3-coef4)-2.*(C12_real.*C13_real+C12_imag.*C13_imag).*(coef3+coef4);
cCubic3 = -(C23_real.^2+C23_imag.^2).*(coef1+coef2)-2.*C11.*C23_real.*(coef3+coef4);
cCubic4 = 2.*(C13_real.^2+C13_imag.^2+C13_real.*C22).*coef2;
cCubic5 = -(C12_real.^2+C12_imag.^2).*(1-coef1+coef2)-2.*C33.*C12_real.*(coef3-coef4);
cCubic = cCubic1+cCubic2-cCubic3-cCubic4-cCubic5;
dCubic1 = C11.*C22.*C33;
dCubic2 = 2.*(C12_real.*(C13_real.*C23_real+C13_imag.*C23_imag)+C12_imag.*(C13_imag.*C23_real-C13_real.*C23_imag));
dCubic3 = C11.*(C23_real.^2+C23_imag.^2);
dCubic4 = C22.*(C13_real.^2+C13_imag.^2);
dCubic5 = C33.*(C12_real.^2+C12_imag.^2);
dCubic = dCubic1+dCubic2-dCubic3-dCubic4-dCubic5;
%// move this down to one block for looping:
%//rCubic = roots([aCubic bCubic cCubic dCubic]);
%//sel3 = rCubic == real(rCubic);
%//rCubic = rCubic(sel3);
%//sel4 = rCubic == abs(rCubic);
%//rCubic = rCubic(sel4);
%//Fv3 = max(rCubic);

Fv_vec = zeros(size(theta));
for k=1:numel(theta)
   rQuadratic = roots([aQuadratic(k) bQuadratic(k) cQuadratic(k)]);
   %//sel1 = rQuadratic == real(rQuadratic);
   %//rQuadratic = rQuadratic(sel1);
   %//sel2 = rQuadratic == abs(rQuadratic);
   %//rQuadratic = rQuadratic(sel2);

   %// suggestion instead: (with optional tol=1e-10 or something else earlier)
   rQuadratic = rQuadratic(abs(rQuadratic-abs(rQuadratic))<1e-10);  % allow some tolerance due to floating-point
   Fv2 = max(rQuadratic);

   rCubic = roots([aCubic(k) bCubic(k) cCubic(k) dCubic(k)]);
   %//sel3 = rCubic == real(rCubic);
   %//rCubic = rCubic(sel3);
   %//sel4 = rCubic == abs(rCubic);
   %//rCubic = rCubic(sel4);
   rCubic = rCubic(abs(rCubic-abs(rCubic))<1e-10);
   Fv3 = max(rCubic);
   Fv_vec(k) = min([Fv1(k); Fv2; Fv3]);  %// Fv1 is a matrix!
end 

end
```

Since you didn't give any sample inputs, I haven't try to come up with one, so I haven't tested it.

What I've done is change every arithmetic operation to their vectorized pairs (`.*`,`./`,`.^`), and restructure the code to use a single loop where the `roots` are being computed. The input `theta` and `sigma` can be matrices now, corresponding to pairs of the input vectors (constructed with `meshgrid`). My solution assumes that all the input parameters are scalars. I've also changed the part for finding the largest absolute value, allowing for some small errors due to floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: I'm doing something like this. Trying to use for loops just for obtaining the roots and then trying to change that small part of the code with a mex file. Is that applicable?

Comment: @sepideh The root finding will probably take up a small part of runtime. You'll have to run the profiler to see what takes up the most runtime, but I suspect all those arithmetic operations. So you should do something like the above, and if it's too slow (and you can't find a bottleneck), then rewrite the whole function (complete with arithmetics) in MEX.

Comment: I have run the profiler and explained about this bottleneck. Please take a look at [Is there anyway to accelerate the process through MEX files? Will this help significantly?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35833598/1245120)